# How to Enable password after lock/Suspend

Tags: login, password, suspend, lock-screen

I tried searching for an answer. But everyone is asking for autologin or disable passwd. But i want to put a password which on my laptop is not enabled. I tried to do this in settings but it won't work. Autologin is off. Brightness and lock settings are below.

[image]

I don't know what else I can do. When I lock the pc, the screen goes black and then simply wakes up to the home screen without any password. Same case happened when I suspend the laptop.

So, how can I be prompted to enter my password each time the computer wakes from sleep or activates the screensaver?

Comment: Could you post the output of `dpkg - l | grep screensaver`? That would help me see if one solution is viable :)

Comment: `Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
`
@RPiAwesomeness

Comment: i am using 14.04 LTS

Comment: And you typed it in exactly as `dpkg -l | grep screensaver`?

Comment: as you said, Yes

Comment: That's definitely not the right output - looks like an error. Did you copy/paste it or did you type it out? Because this: `|` is a vertical bar/pipe, not a capital I - did you get that messed up?

Comment: `ii  gnome-screensaver                                     3.6.1-0ubuntu13                                     amd64        GNOME screen saver and locker
`

Comment: There we go, that's the output I was expecting. Okay, so that throws out *that* solution. Now back to drawing board >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many things but none of them works. and xscreensaver is the only alternative. After searching I finally try to update the ubuntu to the latest stable version from 14.04 to 14.10 via Software Updater and then everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `'/etc/systemd/logind.conf'`

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Removed the # comment from the beginning of the line  'HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore' and changed the value to be:

```
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

Then Reboot your system